# Webpack 5 differend hash for static files

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack 5. For static files (images and fonts) i use:

```
{
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'assets/images/[name][contenthash][ext]',
        },
      },
```

For css i use:

```
{
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[hash:base64]',
              },
            },
          },
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
```

The problem is: that in minified css output file i get links to files with differens hash then the file has itself.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYA9L.png)

If i delete this

```
generator: {
              filename: 'assets/images/[name][contenthash][ext]',
            },
```

Hashes are applyied correctly, but files are not stored as required. And also i'm interested how make it to work with assets/resourses.

Here is my full webpack config:
webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['./src/index.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../build'),
    clean: true,
    publicPath: '../',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', 'react-hot-loader/patch'],
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: ['style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash]',
              },
            },
          },
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
  ],
});
```

webpack.prod.js

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require('image-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[hash:base64]',
              },
            },
          },
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'assets/images/[name][contenthash][ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'assets/fonts/[name][contenthash][ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash].css',
    }),
    new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
      severityError: 'warning',
      minimizerOptions: {
        plugins: [
          ['gifsicle', { interlaced: true }],
          ['jpegtran', { progressive: true }],
          ['optipng', { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
          ['svgo'],
        ],
      },
      loader: false,
    }),
  ],
});
```

**PS: if i change or remove hash in generator prop for assets if works fine. The same file name in css and in file system. But with hash everything breaks again.**

Comment: what is the version of webpack and your loaders?

Comment: hi. "css-loader": "^5.1.2", "webpack": "^5.25.0", "postcss-loader": "^5.2.0", "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",